# WPF. How to align text in InlineUIContainer content with outer text in RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, inlineuicontainer

The task: Make the text content of the InlineUIContainer to be inline with the outer text

The standard behaviour of the InlineUIContainer content is when the bottom edge is inline with the outer text.

It is possible to shift the content of InlineUIContainer with RenderTransform, but the value of Y has to be chosen for each font type and size - not a perfect way.

```
<RichTextBox>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            LLL
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Border Background="LightGoldenrodYellow">
                    <TextBlock Text="LLL"/>
                </Border>
            </InlineUIContainer>
            LLL
        </Paragraph>

        <Paragraph>
            LLL
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Border Background="LightGoldenrodYellow">

                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform Y="5" />
                    </Border.RenderTransform>

                    <TextBlock Text="LLL"/>

                </Border>    
            </InlineUIContainer>
            LLL
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

[image: Example]

How to align the text in the InlineUIContainer content with the outer text in RichTextBox regardless of font type and size?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

have you tried playing around with [InlineUIContainer.BaselineAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.inline.baselinealignment.aspx)

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.baselinealignment.aspx) are some examples for how to use it

Comment: Yes, for WPF <InlineUIContainer BaselineAlignment="Center"> works fine (just checked). Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to update the size of the InlineUIContainer to match its child control?

Comment: @Shimmy what do you mean? the size of the InlineUIContainer *is always* that of its child control